# Change port for shared folder and opening it

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have a server which runs multiple virtual machines using virtualbox. I need to enable file sharing in several of those virtual machines.

I understand that the port for file sharing is the 445, so tried forwarding the port to the 4445 on the host to the 445 on the guest.

I encounter two problems:

1. The port in the host doesn't seem to be listening (a telnet fails to connect).
2. How do I specify the port when connecting, windows explorer and the copy command doesn't look like taking the \ip:port\share notation (returns a network path not found)

I feel that the problem with the first one must be some firewall or alike, do I need to restart the virtual machine after doing the port forwarding?

The second one concerns me a bit more, how can I specify the port?

Comment: I wasnt aware that you could change the port.  Rather than telnet, do netstat -a to show all ports in use, this will show listening and used.  By default it uses 135-139 and 445 the latter being both tcp and udp.